# Quickblox Server Side Chat History Storage Duration & Price

Tags: quickblox

Is there any time limit on how long chat history is stored in Quickblox. The details are not mentioned here -  http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Server-side_chat_history

Also, what would the cost of storage be?

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit on chat history storage in QuickBlox.

Comment: There is no additional cost for storage.